# How can I call a python instance using php?

Tags: php, python, cross-language

I have a PHP program, and a Python program. You can think that the Python program is like a robot or machine. Typically, it will use a database, do some analysis and return result for you. It is a plain text console application.

I would like to let the user use the program via a web interface. So, I would like to use PHP, accept user input, and the pass it to the Python program, and back to the user.

How can I achieve it? The Python program is always running on the server, which will keep analysis data from the web and the user input, so it can't easily convert to become a script on server side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use the search, you will find many questions here how to launch a process from PHP with parameters and get the text output of that process.

Comment: Look at [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), or [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), depending on what you need to do.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php These are the functions on php-doc. I never know which one’s for what ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. You can pass the input from user as parameters to the python script and get back the output from it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into http://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/